# How to pass form name to javascript and use it to read form values

Tags: javascript, jsp

I wanted to know how to pass the form name dynamically and use it to retrieve form values. I used the below code.

```
function validatecbr(form,outagetkt)
{

    var formName = form.name;
    alert(formName);

    var cbr1 = formName.cbr11.value;
    var cbr2 = formName.cbr22.value;
    var cbr3 = formName.cbr33.value;
    var cbrnum = cbr1+cbr2+cbr3;
    if(cbr1.length !=3){
        alert("Please Enter 10 digit Account telephone number");
        formName.cbr11.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(cbr2.length !=3){
        alert("Please Enter 10 digit Account telephone number");
        formName.cbr22.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(cbr3.length !=4){
        alert("Please Enter 10 digit Account telephone number");
        formName.cbr33.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("cbrnum "+cbrnum);

        formName.method="POST";
        formName.action="/support/residential/outage/serviceOutage?cbrnum="+cbrnum+"&btn="+btn+"&outagetkt="+outagetkt;
        formName.submit();
    }
}
```

The below is the body content

```
<body>
    <%int nc=0; %>

        <div id="KMU_alerts">
            Contact me with alternative notification phone number1.
            <%nc++; %>
                <form name="kmuform<%=nc%>" id="kmuform<%=nc%>" action="javascript:validatecbr(document.kmuform<%=nc%>,'outage');">
                    <input type="text" name="cbr1" id="cbr11"
                    onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="3"
                    size="2" />

                    <input type="text" name="cbr2" id="cbr22"
                    onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="3"
                    size="2" />

                    <input type="text" name="cbr3" id="cbr33"
                    onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="4"
                    size="2" />

                    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:validatecbr(document.kmuform<%=nc%>,'outage');"/>
                </form>
        </div>

        <div id="KMU_alerts">
            Contact me with alternative notification phone number2.
            <%nc++; %>
            <form name="kmuform<%=nc%>">
                <input type="text" name="cbr1" id="cbr11"
                onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="3"
                size="2" />

                <input type="text" name="cbr2" id="cbr22"
                onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="3"
                size="2" />

                <input type="text" name="cbr3" id="cbr33"
                onpaste="return false;" style="width: 35px;" maxlength="4"
                size="2" />

                <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:validatecbr(this.form,'outage');"/>
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

But the code is showing "'cbr11.value' is null or not an object" at "formName.cbr11.value;" this line..

Can someone pls tell me how to pass the form name to a js function and use it to read the form values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var formName = form.name;

formName here is a string and not an HTMLFormElement Object

Access the form field's values using the form object

```
var cbr1 = form.cbr11.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of reducing the code, you can refer below @Phanimadhavi Vasantala.

```
function validatecbr(form,outagetkt)
{

    var cbr1 = form.cbr11.value;
    var cbr2 = form.cbr22.value;
    var cbr3 = form.cbr33.value;
    var cbrnum = cbr1+cbr2+cbr3;
    if(cbr1.length !=3){
        dispalyErrorAndFocus(form.cbr11);   
    }
    else if(cbr2.length !=3){
        dispalyErrorAndFocus(form.cbr22);   
    }
    else if(cbr3.length !=4){
        dispalyErrorAndFocus(form.cbr33);   
    }
    else
    {
        alert("cbrnum "+cbrnum);

        formName.method="POST";
        formName.action="/support/residential/outage/serviceOutage?cbrnum="+cbrnum+"&btn="+btn+"&outagetkt="+outagetkt;
        formName.submit();
    }
}


function dispalyErrorAndFocus(CompRef) {
    alert("Please Enter 10 digit Account telephone number");
    CompRef.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Even you can, set the error message to some variable and make it generic.

Thanks